# Gatling and Azure DevOps server on prem

Tags: azure-devops, gatling

I’m using Gatling on my local machine. Now I need to move tests to our Azure DevOps server on prem version.
Anyone who has done this? I’ve not found a tutorial for this.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using the Azure Devops Server, you need to create a [Self-hosted agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#install).

Then you can use your local script to run the gatling test.

Here is my maven gatling test example:

Yaml sample:

```
steps:
- task: Maven@3
  displayName: 'Maven pom.xml'

- powershell: 'mvn gatling:test'
  workingDirectory: '$(build.sourcesdirectory)'
  displayName: 'PowerShell Script'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact: drop'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.sourcesdirectory)'
```

Comment: Ok so on my self hosted agent: I install Gatling and my tests?

Comment: @user3624378  yes, you are right. you need to configure the test environment on your self hosted agent. then you could do the test in Azure Devops server pipeline.

Comment: Hi, do you have an example of pom.xml-file?

Comment: @user3624378. sure. Please refer to this sample: https://github.com/gatling/gatling-maven-plugin-demo